# Cordova icon / splashscreen issue

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

For the life of me I can't figure out why the icon is all huge and not disappearing when the splash screen on my Cordova iPhone app shows up. Here is it shown on the iPhone 6. It also happens when tested on an iPhone 6 Plus. For some reason it doesn't have this effect on the iPhone X.

[image: cordova icon issue?]

Is there some sort of config.xml preference or some undocumented change that I'm not making?

Comment: Or is this standard default behavior for app icons?

Comment: yhea, I've spotted this issue too on two of my apps (I think it appeared when I started to use the new splashscreen system for iOS). I've reported it there : https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CB/issues/CB-13900 Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No. Haven’t found a solution.